# Vim on Debian, configuration issues

Tags: vimrc, linux-debian, default-settings

I have been working with a stock vim configuration for a long time. I want to modify just a couple of settings. I don't want to lose the rest of the default configuration.

If I create a new `.vimrc` I lose all the default settings.
If I `cp /usr/share/vim/vimrc ~/.vimrc` I lose all the default settings.
If I `cp /etc/vim/vimrc ~/.vimrc` I lose all the default settings.

How can I retain the default system wide settings, while overriding the few particular settings that I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/usr/share/vim/vimrc` is always sourced regardless of your vimrc (assuming `$VIM` doesn't point somewhere else - `:h system-vimrc`). The settings you're probably missing are in `defaults.vim`, a file that *only* gets sourced if you don't have a personal vimrc. To get them back add these two lines to your vimrc:

```
unlet! skip_defaults_vim
source $VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim
```

Check the rest of the help on the subject on `:h defaults.vim`

My information might be wrong however. I'm assuming here you're running vim 8, first included in debian 9. Unfortunately the only current debian system I can check is still running debian 8 stable, where vim doesn't have `defaults.vim`.

Comment: Also see: [A rant on defaults.vim in Vim 8](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/66vjm8/a_rant_on_defaultsvim_in_vim_8/). The `defaults.vim` behaviour can be really confusing.

Comment: See also my attempt at advocating for Vim to change this to be more logical -- https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/2042#issuecomment-328657433