# Why does an empty vimrc file change my configuration (e.g. disable syntax highlighting)?

Tags: vimrc, syntax-highlighting

Here is the *sshconfig* syntax highlighting when i do not have any *.vimrc* file:

[image]

Let's create an *empty* *.virmc* :

$touch ~/.vimrc

Now let's edit that same file again:

[image]

Why is this happening?  I'd like to use ~/.vimrc but not if it breaks syntax coloring.  I am using brew-installed *macvim* on *macOS Big Sur*

Comment: Related: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/23036/10604, https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/16102/10604. I thought we had a comprehensive duplicate for this but I can't find it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because Vim is using `$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim` as the vimrc file.

If you look at `:h .vimrc` you'll see that Vim looks in five places for a vimrc file, stopping once it's found one.

When you have an empty personal vimrc (in your home directory, usually) then Vim will read that and stop searching. Obviously, if the file is empty there's no configuration of file type detection and, thus, no syntax highlighting.

When you *don't* have a personal vimrc then Vim continues down the list until it gets to the last item which is defaults.vim. This vimrc file includes `filetype on` and `syntax on` which enable file type detection and syntax highlighting, respectively.

Note that to truly work without a vimrc you'd need to use the `-u NONE` flag when you run Vim.

Comment: Oh that's surprising. Most configuration systems acquire "defaults" for each setting and then selectively override them with user-supplied values.  I'll look up how to apply the vim defaults from within my .vimrc

Comment: Indeed, this takes a lot of people by surprise. I think it's at least partly due to the fact that default configuration (i.e. no vimrc file at all) has become pretty outdated over the years (for instance, `compatible` is enabled...ick) so `defaults.vim` was added as kind of a user-friendly band aid.  (FYI,add `source $VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim` to the start of your vimrc if you want to include it.) Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @BLayer's [accepted] answer: the *~/.vimrc* can "extend" the *defaults.vim* :

```
source $VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim   " Add this to your ~/.vimrc
```

In this way we do not lose the world [default settings] for a penny [one particular setting].

Comment: Also `runtime defaults.vim`